# automate filesystem expansion - booting from a USB Drive (8GB Image burned to 32GB USB)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, linux, partition

I have an 8GB image that is burned to a 32GB USB drive.

How can I automate this filesystem expansion process? Is there a script I can create to expand the USB correctly and fully? How can I find the exact partition size needed? I noticed when I manually expand the filesystem it only increases the size in **/dev/sda2** not **/dev/sda1**.

1) I have seen a suggestion to use

```
parted /dev/sda resizepart 1 102400 # resize /dev/sda1 to 100GB
resize2fs /dev/sda1 # resize filesystem
```

In this method, I am unsure how to calculate the value needed to ensure full expansion. I have used `fdisk -l` but unsure how to use the data here for the command above.

2) I have looked at the **/usr/bin/raspi-config** file and don't fully understand what I need to extract from the `--expand-rootfs` section of the file for my needs.

--- RESULTS FROM `fdisk -l` ---

**8GB Image manually expanded on 32GB USB**

```
Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       2048 62332927 62330880 29.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sda: 28.7 GiB, 30752000000 bytes, 60062500 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8f1eafaf

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         8192   131071   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2       131072 60062499 59931428 28.6G 83 Linux
```

**8GB Image awaiting expansion on 32GB USB**

```
Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       8192 62333951 62325760 29.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sda: 28.7 GiB, 30752636928 bytes, 60063744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb9da48fc

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         8192   131071   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2       131072 15523839 15392768  7.3G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Rasbpian already does this on first boot!

Comment: @Milliways it expands the filesystem on boot? I can assure you it does not. My Image is 8GB but it is burned to a 32GB USB. I Need to fill the remaining space. Manually entering "raspi-config" and expand filesystem completes the task. I need to automate the process

Answer (score 3):

On the very first boot of a virgin Raspbian image there is running a script that you can find in `/boot/cmdline.txt` before booting first time. This is from *Rasbian Buster Lite 2020-02-13*:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh
```

As you see there is `/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh` called but after the first boot this entry in `/boot/cmdline.txt` is removed so you will not find it on following bootups. If your image does not resize the partition on first boot then either it isn't a Raspbian image or it has already booted before.

You may have a look at this script how resizing of a partition works. Maybe you can just copy it?

Comment: Is this only for SD card booting? Recall I am booting from the USB

Comment: @presish This is for the Raspbian image. There is the `init_resize.sh` script located, no matter if you flash it to the SD Card or to an USB stick. But I don't know if the script detects on what storage it is running. Maybe you have to modify it.

Comment: Yes I believe it needs modification. I used it on the USB and did not work. Will need to look into this more unless you know what needs to be modified